# How do I change the upgrade authority of a program?

Tags: solana-program

Say I have my live program at account `X` and it's upgrade authority is held by `A`. How do I transfer the upgrade authority to `B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, I can use the [`set_upgrade_authority`](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/bpf_loader_upgradeable/fn.set_upgrade_authority.html) instruction:

```
set_upgrade_authority(&X,&A,&B)
```

Comment: can you share how to upgrade via Javascript by upgrade authority?

I wonder if this work flow viable : developer give a new program so file to a dedicate admin , who then sign upgrade Tx offline  and send back to developer to perform upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Using the CLI you could do `solana program set-upgrade-authority`